# Regular Expression to Exclude First Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a div that I am trying to run a regular expression on

```
<div class="module-header-content module-default">
```

I am using this replace operation that used to work,but  now that I have added the module-header-content class it becomes problematic

```
replace(/module-\w+/gi, ' ');
```

I need a regular expression that removes all instances of module- except for module-header-content

Any help.

Thanks

The entire call:

```
        var $target = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();


        //// Removes all module-xxxx classes
        var classes = $target[0].className.replace(/module-\w+/gi, '');
```

Comment: Quick comment, that multi `.parent()` is hideous.  Does the target parent have an ID, you can use `.closest('#parentID')`.

Comment: Was what was already in place, at some point I will clean that up, but yes it is ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = "module-header-content module-default module-default-foo module-default-foo-bar";
str.replace(/module(?!-header)(-\w+)*/gi, '');
```

It'll get all classes except "module-header-content".

Comment: I don't know if all `-header` classes are excluded, OP only stated `-header-content`, otherwise cool. :-)

Comment: How about `module-header`? ;-)

Comment: While the rest were very informative, I actually ended up using your reg ex. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the negative that masher showed, so the regex change to: str.replace(/module(?!-header-content)(-\w+)*/gi, '');

Answer (score 5):

You need a negative lookahead.

`module-(?!header-content)\w+`

Comment: (Beat me to it) Nice to see someone else not immediately saying, *Thou shalt parse HTML* - though I do think the regex should at least have the `class=""` bit surrounding it for protection against text occurrences, not that it is very likely in this code, but could occur in an ID.

Comment: @Orbling: The problem is once you start trying to detect context, where do you stop? Once you start tweaking the regex to add more cases and more complexity, it's a very, very short road to trying to parse HTML in its entirety.

Comment: @Anon. To answer your question, with pattern matching, for that is what Regexp is for, you look at the domain and make assumptions on it.  If it is your own code, then you can guarantee your assumptions.

Comment: @Anon. In this example, I think the OP has already got to the element and needs to detect and remove any class starting with `module-` - note using jQuery already (in tags).  There is precious little alternative to the regexp.

Comment: So just so I have this correct my entire call would be:

str.replace(module-(?!header-content)\w+, '');

Comment: @Orbling: It's pretty straightforward to add and remove CSS classes with jQuery.

Comment: @Orbling I'm under the impression that the OP is just dealing with the attribute value after having extracted it using DOM/jQuery/whatever. Given that, I don't understand your suggestion about having `class=""` in the regex...

Comment: @Anon.: jQuery is one of my primary development languages. None of the class manipulation methods support wildcard matching.  Sizzle sort of can match elements if you use `[className*= module-]`, but that is no further help in removing it.  A regexp is the preferred method.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: Entirely correct, noticed that afterwards while arguing the same point in an earlier comment - but comments can not be edited once more are added.

Comment: @Orbling: So why not just get the names of the class elements you're interested in and remove them one-by-one?

Comment: @Anon.: a) The list may not be finite, or at least not known; b) That would be significantly less efficient.  Why the hatred of regexp?  This is a classic target use-case for them.

Comment: @Orbling: That response was with regards to your claim that matching elements is no help in removing them. Perhaps I should have included "that the element has that you're interested in". With regards to regular expressions, if they're truly necessary in this case to work around shortcomings in jQuery then that's okay, but to suddenly *stop* treating something as a structured document and start operating on it as raw text is *never* a "classic target use case".

Comment: @Anon. But it isn't a structured document here, it is a `className` attribute, a *space-separated list of class names*.  Also, it is not a shortcoming of jQuery, how do you think Sizzle implements the pattern matching in the first place?

Comment: @Orbling: That's like suggesting that it's acceptable to reinvent the wheel every time you need a new hashtable or linked list, because how do you think the STL does it in the first place?

Comment: @Anon.: jQuery does not have pattern matching for classes, why, probably lack of demand.  If they did have it, it would be via regexp.  A quick look at the jQuery code (v1.4.4) shows up the following regexp uses, 69 x `.test()`, 41 x `.replace()` and even 5 x direct `RegExp()` instantiations.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [masher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404556/regular-expression-to-exclude-first-item/4404584#4404584), lots of programmers know about using parentheses to get matches within a regex, but the very useful non-matching parentheses are not as well known.

`/(foo)/` will match `foo` and store it in the matches array. But what if you don't want a match to be stored? In that case, you can use `?:` inside the parentheses: `/(?:foo)/` . This will match the pattern but not store it in the matches array.

You can also search for anything except what is inside the parentheses with `?!` so `/(?!foo)/` will match anything except 'foo'. If you wanted to store the match, you'd use `/[^(foo)]/` .

Yes, regular expressions are wonderful.

Comment: :) Thanks. You can tell I like regular expressions!

Comment: @bowsersenior Yes, I love them and fight their corner here a lot for some reason, as a lot of people seem to hate them.  I think they need to read Mastering Regular Expressions. Also could do with learning that PCRE is far more than the grammar-class-restricted ancient regexp they are thinking of. *[NB. Nearly did not notice that message, as there was no @Orbling on it, people only get notified of messages if it is their question, their answer, or directly addressed.]*

Comment: @Orbling I should pick up a copy of Mastering Regular Expressions one of these days. Also, thanks for the tip on the notifications. I did not know that. I'm a regex old-timer but a Stack Overflow noob!

Comment: @bowsersenior Me too, only been answering questions on here three weeks.  Still learning the ropes, and apparently annoying the unbelievers.  I came upon them via Perl, which I think is a common route for those that love them.

Comment: @Orbling Perl took regex to the next level (though I admit I am a zealous Rubyist). I myself got into regex via text editors while massaging CSVs and other data dumps. Keep up the good fight, the unbelievers are legion.

Comment: @bowsersenior I am an emacs man, and consider `M-C-%` the most useful shortcut this side of wipe (C-w). (vim has it too `:s/../../`)